# Move multiple panels with Mouse

Tags: c#, winforms, mouse, panel

I have a main Panel where I create some panel that I can drag & move. (The user can add panels)

Here is the code of my public class ObjetGrafcet: Panel,

(UserControlGraf.SelectionActuelle is a List where are added user-selected panels)

```
public ObjetGrafcet()
    {
        Redimension = false;
        isClicked = false;
        onMove = false;
        this.DoubleBuffered = true;
        this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseUp(e);
        foreach (Control ctr in UserControlGraf.SelectionActuelle)
        {
            if (onMove)
            {
                ctr.Left = ctr.Left - (ctr.Left % UserControlGraf.IntervalleGrilleX);
                ctr.Top = ctr.Top - (ctr.Top % UserControlGraf.IntervalleGrilleY);
            }
            if(ctr is Ligne)
            {
                ctr.Left += 1;
            }
        }
        Redimension = false;
        onMove = false;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left && !UserControlGraf.SelectionActuelle.Contains(this))
        {
            isClicked = true;
            Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
            UserControlGraf.SelectionActuelle.Add(this);

            //Permet la selection d'un seul objet grafcet
            if (UserControlGraf.SelectionActuelle.Count == 2)
            {
                ((ObjetGrafcet)UserControlGraf.SelectionActuelle[0]).isClicked = false;
                ((ObjetGrafcet)UserControlGraf.SelectionActuelle[0]).Refresh();
                UserControlGraf.SelectionActuelle.RemoveAt(0);
            }
            if(this is TextFieldGraf)
            {
                if(e.X > this.Width-10 && e.Y > this.Height - 10)
                {
                    Redimension = true;
                }
            }

            this.Refresh();
        }
        DepartSouris = new Point(e.X, e.Y);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            if (this is TextFieldGraf)
            {
                if (e.X > this.Width - 10 && e.Y > this.Height - 10)
                {
                    Redimension = true;
                }
            }
            if (Redimension)
            {
                this.Width = e.X  - (e.X % UserControlGraf.IntervalleGrilleX);
                this.Height = e.Y  - (e.Y % UserControlGraf.IntervalleGrilleY);
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (Control ctr in UserControlGraf.SelectionActuelle)
                {
                    ctr.Left = e.X + ctr.Left - DepartSouris.X;
                    ctr.Top = e.Y + ctr.Top - DepartSouris.Y;
                }
                onMove = true;
            }
        }
        this.Refresh();
    }
```

The problem is when I try to move my Panels its lagging really hard. It's not fluid as I want. I through my foreach was the cause (may be because it's a slow function?) But I don't know how to do in a different way.

What's the problem with my code?

Here is a screenshot of what I obtain. My lines are pobject inherited from ObjetGrafcet. This is when I move more than 4/5 lines.
http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2016/52/1483006418-bugerror.png

Comment: Maybe add a [`this.SuspendLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.suspendlayout(v=vs.110).aspx) before you start the loop/move and call ResumeLayout when done?

Comment: I tried, but it's not working.

Comment: I tried to refresh the parent. It's working well for the lags but It adds flickering.

Comment: Is the Form also double-buffered? (If they are indeed sitting on the form..)

Comment: Thanks TaW for your answer. It was not the form but the Panel where I add other panels. I put it DoubleBuffered and it works fine !